# SEO friendly URLs in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, seo

Let's say I have a relatively basic CRUD application for editing music albums.  In the database I have:

```
id | album_name | artist  |  navigation

1    Lets Talk   Lagwagon    lets-talk
```

However, instead of `albums/1` returning my `Show` page, I want the page to be accessible by the `albums/lets-talk` route.

So in my controller I have:

```
  def show
    @album = Album.find_by_navigation(params[:id])
  end
```

And in my index view I have:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', :controller => "albums", :action => "show", :id => album.navigation %>
```

This successfully performs its function, however, the Ruby API says my link_to method is old and archaic without listing an alternative, so I suspect I'm going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. It is exactly what you need.

Comment: Sergey, This was precisely what I needed, thanks.  

@TylerDeWitt Thanks for the link, I somehow missed it when I was scouring RailsCasts for a solution last night.

Answer (score 17):

Define your to_param in the model:

```
class album
    def to_param
        "#{id}-#{album-name.parameterize}"
     end
end
```

Now you can use

```
<%= link_to album.album_name, album %>
```

to create the link to the seo path

Then in your controller:

```
Album.find(params[:id])
```

will call `to_i` -> so you get the `Topic.find(2133)` or whatever.

This will result in urls of the form: "/album/2-dark-side-of-the-moon"  which although not exactly what was asked for has advantages - The id is used to find the album - which is unique, when the name might not be.

The parameterize method "Replaces special characters in a string so that it may be used as part of a ‘pretty’ URL" - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize

Comment: why the downvote? This is how this is done in the Rails Best Practices course at codeschool. Seems to work well on projects Iv'e done.  Have i missed the point of the question?

Comment: Wasn't downvoted by me, I just read it.  While I'm not utilizing this particular solution this time, I appreciate the information.  How is codeschool?  Worth it?

Comment: First, with "#{id}-#{album-name.parameterize}", your url will be /album/2-lets-talk, not /album/lets-talk. Second, with non-latin names when you use parametrize then the name in the link will be different from the name of the object, this case not match question. Thats why downvote.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the feedback.  Iv'e updated my answer to indicate why you might not want to rely on the album name. It's a possible way to tackle this sort of problem. Just using the Name unaltered is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display URL in browser as `app/albums/lets-talk` but POST params as `album_id => 1`, for shopping cart addition etc.

In your album model:

```
# PRODUCT MODEL
 before_create do
   self.navigation = album_name.downcase.gsub(" ", "-")  
  end

def to_param
    [id, album_name.parameterize].join("-")
end
```

Now you can

```
@album = Album.find_by_navigation(params[:id])
```

and

```
album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you whant to override :id parameter to :name parameter. This case described in [this article](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    name
  end
end

user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
link_to 'Show', user_path(user)  # => <a href="/users/Phusion">Show</a>
```