# How do I re-write this route to be shorter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have `resources :tags` in my `routes.rb`.

So when I go to `/tags/ios`, it shows me the correct `Tag#Show` view.

What I would like to happen is when the user goes to `/tags/ios`it shows it as `/ios` and likewise I want that generated path to always be `/ios` (and not have the leading `/tags`).

Here is an example of how I am rendering that link, within an `each` block:

```
<%= link_to "#{tag.name}", url_for(tag) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even though I got lots of nice suggestions from these guys, I found what I think is the best solution for me.

All I am trying to do is basically make `/tags/ruby` be rendered as `/ruby` both in the actual URL on the links of all the tags, and in the URL bar.

I don't want to do anything that will add load to my app.

This is the solution that works for me:

```
resources :tags, path: "", except: [:index, :new, :create]
```

Using `path:`, you can specify what you want the path to display as. i.e. what do you want to appear before your resource. So if you wanted your URLs to look like `myhotness/tags/ruby`, then you would simply do `path: "myhotness"`.

I didn't want anything in my path, so I just left it blank.

For what it's worth, you can even add a constraint to that route, like so:

```
resources :tags, path: "", except: [:index, :new, :create], constraints: { :id => /.*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

well the problem here is namespace

if you define a route like

get "/(:slug)" => "Tags#show"

that will basically match anything where its a valid tag or not. The way I would do it would be

in your routes file:

```
  begin  
    Tag.all.each do |t|
      begin
        get "#{t.slug}" => "Tags#show"
      rescue
      end
    end
  rescue
  end
```

Then in your tags controller you can

```
 def show
    slug = request.env['PATH_INFO']
    @tag = Tag.find_by_slug(slug)
  end
```

My answer comes from another answer I wrote that you may be interested [How to create app-wide slug routing for Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375222/how-to-create-app-wide-slug-routing-for-rails-app/15394197#15394197)

Comment: I am not using a slug. Just the `name` attribute of `Tag`.

Comment: That's a neat way to do it. What's with all the `rescue`s though... do you not trust your own code?

Comment: This seems a bit heavy handed and inefficient, no?. On each request, I will be doing a `Tag.all.each`. In my case, I have 1300+ tags, so I can see that being pretty ugly, really quick - or am I missing something?

Comment: In production the routes are, for lack of a better word, compiled. That would only happen once when you start the server.

Comment: you can probably remove the rescues, in a sense i don't trust my own code. For instance routes are loaded when you run rake for some reason, so rake db:migrate could fail when first deploying to a new server since t.slug and the tag table would not exist

Comment: I think I found the best solution for me. Simple and elegant. I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.rb

```
resources :tags
match '/:tag_name' => 'tags#show'
```

Then in your tags_controller#show action you have access to the tag name via:

```
params[:tag_name]
```

Be sure to put that at the end of your routes file, as it will catch everything. Also, since it will catch everything you should render a 404 if it's not a valid tag name:

```
def show
    unless @tag = Tag.where(name: params[:tag_name]).first
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
    end
end
```

To redirect /tags/ruby to /ruby:

```
match "/tags/:tag_name" => redirect("/%{tag_name}")
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: When I am on a URL like this: `http://localhost:3000/tags/ruby-on-rails`, this is what the params looks like: `Request parameters 
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"tags", "id"=>"ruby-on-rails"}`

Comment: if you want it to match that, then simply use `match '/:id' => 'tags#show'`

Comment: Ok....perfect...so now `/tags/ruby-on-rails` goes to the same place as `/ruby-on-rails`. But...the path generated in each link is still `/tags/ruby-on-rails`. Also...if the user goes to `/tags/ruby` I want the URL in the address bar to read `/ruby`. So I don't just want a match, but basically a URL re-write and the same in the `url_for` paths that are generated.

Comment: Updated the answer with the redirection part. Not sure about making `link_to @tag` work correctly off the top of my head. Make another post on here for that part.

Comment: I even tried `match "/tags/:id" => redirect("/%{id}")`, but that doesn't work. I actually am not really looking for an official `redirect`. More like a route mask or something like that.

Comment: the issue here is doing anything else besides tags and conflicting with the "capture" group. What if i also want a page: /:page_name

Comment: I think I found the best solution for me. Simple and elegant. I wrote it as an answer.