# Dynamic named routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a simple problem where in a routes/url name is determined by a user role. Currently the route displayed is `/new_admin/dispensaries`. If the user has a role of either manager or executive then the named route should be '/dashboards/dispensaries'.

It's kind of simple but the hard part is that in my routes.rb:

namespace :new_admin do
    resources :vendor_templates
    resources :markdown_docs
    resources :email_lists

```
namespace :moderation do
  resources :reported_reviews
end

resources :users do
  member do
    get :user_bans
    post :ban_unban, to: 'user_bans#create'
    delete :ban_unban, to: 'user_bans#destroy'
  end
end

# TODO - this should be written generically to support dispensary/doctors/whatever
get '/dispensaries/reviews', :to => "reviews#all", :as => :all_reviews
get '/dispensaries/pictures', :to => "pictures#all", :as => :all_pictures
get '/dispensaries/videos', :to => "videos#all", :as => :all_videos
get "/dispensaries/autocomplete", to: "dispensaries#autocomplete"

resources :vendors do
  resources :ownership_transfers, only: [:new, :create]
end
...
```

I'm kind of stuck since if I change the new_admin routes, so many other routes will be affected. Any idea guys?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Why not create a new namespace for dashboard, and redirect any managers or executives to the new path?

Comment: Because I'm still new to rails that's why. Let me try that.

Comment: Sorry if that sounded condescending. The solution was a bit obvious to me :)

Comment: It's alright. I'm sorry too for being oversensitive, I should be prepared for anything since it's the internet.

Answer (score 0):

We've actually done something like this. It's not pretty, but this solution worked for us:

---

**Slugs**

You're basically alluding to a type of your routes called [Slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375222/how-to-create-app-wide-slug-routing-for-rails-app). This is where you use a name instead of an ID, allowing you to make a user-friendly route (such as `/delivery/today`). The problem is that in order to create these routes, you have to define them individually in the routes file

There are two Gems you can use to handle your slugged routes -- [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) & [Slugalicious](https://github.com/RISCfuture/slugalicious). Both of these allow you to create slugged routes, but FriendlyID basically just changes the ID, whilst Slugalicious is a totally independent system

We used Slugalicious for the code below, however, you'll probably want FriendlyID (there's a [RailsCast for it here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)):

[image]

---

**Routing**

The problem you have is that routes are outside the scope of the RESTful controller interface, which means you'll have to call all the routes exclusive of your `resources` references in the routes.rb file

If you use Slugalicious, it has its own `Slugs` database, which means we can use it to create the routes on the fly, like this:

```
  #Slugs
  begin  
          Slug.all.each do |s|
                begin
                  get "#{s.slug}" => "#{s.sluggable_type.downcase.pluralize}#show", :id => s.slug
                rescue
                end
          end
  rescue
  end
```

This is live code, and outputs all the slugs in the routes file dynamically. The way we managed to get this to update programmatically was to use an Observer Class like this:

```
class SlugObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(slug)
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end

  def after_destroy(slug)
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end
end
```

I appreciate you may have your answer already, but as you're a beginner, I felt I could help out by explaining the slug stuff for you