# how to using twice id inside route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

i have routes like this :

```
get "/:article_id" => "categories#show", as: :articles_category
get '/:account_id' => "accounts#show", as: :show_account
```

but why when i access show_account_url, i always entry to articles_category_url ??

why?

how to make my routes have twice "/:id" in url with different action?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. Will you be able to differentiate between `xyz.com/15` and `xyz.com/30`, which one is the `show_account_url` and `articles_category_url`. No? When, we being human can't get it then how would we teach the machine to do the same? As simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

> But why when i access `show_account_url`, i always entry to
>   `articles_category_url` ??

The problem you have is you're trying to access the same URL -- `domain.com/______`. Because Rails cannot process the difference, it uses the first route - your `category_url`.

---

There are two ways to deal with this:

> 1. Have a "Routing" controller / use slugs
> 2. Split your routes up conventionally

Everyone wants [app-wide slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375222/how-to-create-app-wide-slug-routing-for-rails-app),  but you can't do it unless you have a mechanism to calculate which URL is correct. The methods you have to achieve this are either to create a routing controller, or use [slugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL).

Using a routing controller is actually quite simple:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "/:id" => "router#direct", as: :slug

#app/controllers/routers_controller.rb
def direct
    #routing code (lots of ifs etc)
end
```

A better way is to use a slug system, which allows you to route to your slugs directly. We use this with http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk & the [slugalicious gem](https://github.com/RISCfuture/slugalicious):

```
#Slugs
  begin  
      Slug.all.each do |s|
        begin
          get "#{s.slug}" => "#{s.sluggable_type.downcase.pluralize}#show", :id => s.slug
        rescue
        end
      end
  rescue
  end
```

This allows you to send specific slugs to specific controllers / actions. The reason? It creates `/[slug]` routes, which you can access across the site

Further to this, you could look at the [`friendly_id` gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) -- which helps you create resourceful routes using slugs. Highly recommended