# Rails Routes and excluding default routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a home controller which I am planing to use just for pages such as aboutus, contactus, or landing page etc. What is the best way to include this in the routes file that I do not get the default routes at all but do get to access each of the actions as a /[action] from the root of the site.

eg:

```
xyz.com/aboutus should take me to home#aboutus
xyz.com/contactus should take me to home#contactus
```

etc.

Comment: use 'as: path_name' attributes in routes.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this `get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'`?

Comment: I do not think I worded my question right. I want to be able to have the xyz.com/aboutus to show the content of the aboutus action under the home controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :home, path: "", only: [] do
   collection do
      get :aboutus
      get :contactus
   end
end
```

> Loop removed by `@Sanket`

This will create `domain.com/aboutus` etc for all your pages

--

**DRY**

Although this is what you want, a much DRYer way to get it to work is to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :home, path: "", only: :show #-> domain.com/:id
```

This means you can then use a gem such as [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to create a series of slugs for your pages, like this:

```
#app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

    #fields
    id | slug | title | body | created_at | updated_at
end

#app/controllers/home_controller.rb
def show
   @page = Page.find params[:id]
end
```

If you just want to render the pages without the model:

```
#app/controllers/home_controller.rb
def show
   render "pages##{params[:id]}"
end
```

This will allow you to use the likes of `domain.com/home/aboutus` in the most DRY way

--

**Caveat**

A big caveat to this is if you're going to be using [app-wide slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375222/how-to-create-app-wide-slug-routing-for-rails-app), you need to put them at the bottom of your `routes.rb` file (so they will not interfere with other routes)

Comment: This is correct but do you think that it has more time-complexity.

Comment: Yep I'm writing a better way to do it now :)

Comment: the issue is I do not want to get the `domain.com/home/about`. I want to be able to go to `domain.com/aboutus` which should show the content of aboutus action user the home controller.

Comment: i may sound like a complete fool here but this looks like too much work for something which does not even have a model in the background.  Should I not use the `match` and add the info that way?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. This works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: I also updated to include a system if you just had static pages (I.E no model)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage a good gem for static pages.

Comment: This also looks promising but why add a gem if something can be achieved with very few lines of code.

Comment: this gem is very useful and complete to achieve this task. Not necessary to rewrite code exist.