# Categories :id to :name in link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, ruby-on-rails-4

I added Categories to my app and trying to get the ugly id in the link to dissapear. (**I'm on Rails 4**)

Without any much Luck.

Currently i have

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/1
```

Every Category has a name, how can i change the categories link to display the `NAME` and not the `ID` of that category.

e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/atoms
```

Comment: Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082336/seo-friendly-urls-in-ror/15083439#15083439

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement `Category#to_param` method:

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

This method is used internally in Rails to generate appropriate urls to your resources. More info here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/to_param

Don't forget changing

```
Category.find(params[:id])
```

to:

```
Category.find_by_name!(params[:id])
```

as you will be searching for the proper category with name instead of id from now on.

Comment: Could you explain that a little bit more (edit) ? (Im relatively new to Rails). I would help me a lot if you state where i put the various changes. Thank you !

Comment: @TheMiniJohn - I expanded my answer. If you have more questions - please be a little bit more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much Marek, i got it :) You rock!

Answer (score 2):

Although Marek Lipka's answer is correct and will work, I usually like using the gem [friendly-id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to do it for me. It has some additional benefits that which are mentioned in the link below.

Ryan Bates covered it in [Railscasts #314](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) as well.

Comment: I tried Friendly-id a while ago, but got stuck on some Rails4 changes. But i will definitely check it out again :) Thank you