# How to set the id of a post to it's title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm guessing this is fairly obvious, but I've been searching for a while and couldn't find anything. So what I want to do is have the `id` of a `link` be the same as `@link.product` How do I do that. Right now in my `links` controller I have

```
def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)
    @link.id = @link.product
end
```

But I still have `/links/5` How do I change the ID so it shows up as `/links/product-name` ?

Comment: if you want to replace id in URL with product-name then I think gem 'friendly_id' will be helpfull.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEO friendly URLs in RoR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082336/seo-friendly-urls-in-ror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suggesting to use "Friendly_id" in [LINK](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), it allows to use `.find` with slug.

**Usage:**

```
# both will be available
/links/5
/links/product-name
```

**Installation:**

```
# in gemfile
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
```

**Install in rails**

```
bundle install
rails generate friendly_id
rails g migration add_slug_to_links slug:string:uniq
rake db:migrate
```

**Link.rb**

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :product, use: :slugged
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)
    @link.save
end
```